# problems updating gradle 3.3.0 to gradle 8.0.2 google storage samples library implementation (project(':resources') fails

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to make the google storage samples library work in the current environment.  I have most of it compiling but I'm not finding the common layout files.
The files are under a directory named resources that is at the same level as the app directory.
The app/build.gradle is a single line saying "apply from: '../common.gradle'".
The resources directory has a build directory, a src directory and a build.gradle file.
The line giving the problem was "compile project(':resources')" under gradle 3 and I changed it to "implementation (project(':resources'))" for gradle 8 which from the documents looks like it should work and Gradle update is ok.  I tried project(':resources/src') but that doesn't work.
gradle resources:assembleDebug is ok but gradlew assembleDebug seems unable to find any of the resources files.
The resources/build/.../R.txt has the labels I need and seems to build ok.
The examples in [Declaring Dependencies between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html) look right.  I'm stuck.  What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**  It turned out I had a typo in app/build.gradle namespace so thr R file wasn't being found.  Duh...